# Samsung RS275 fridge: no water filter indicator reset

Tags: refrigerator, filter

The water filter replacement indicator on our RS275 refrigerator will not reset. Things I tried so far:

- pressing the filter reset button for three seconds (it beeps, but the indicator light stays on)
- replacing the filter (no effect)
- pressing the ice type+child lock buttons (other Samsung fridges reset the filter replacement indicator this way).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pressing the wrong button, press and hold the "Ice Type" button to reset. From the Owners Manual:

> • Change filter every 6 months. If indicator is purple, the filter has 1 month left.
>   If indicator is red, quick replacement is strongly recommended.
>   • When the water filter is replaced, reset the indicator by pressing the Ice Type
>   button for 3 seconds.
>   • To turn this indicator off, press the Ice Type and Child Lock buttons simultaneously
>   and hold for 5 seconds.

[image]

Note: the light will "stay on", but it will change color to green. I personally have difficulty with this because of mild red-green color vision deficiency, and must have another family member confirm when the LED color change has occured.

Comment: tried three times Ice Type... it beeps but does nothing. The {Ice Type + Child Lock} combo instead worked on the second try. Thanks!